# Axios returns undefined in nested Vue JS (Laravel API)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm having a lot of trouble with Axios when using nested routes in Vue JS.

I have found that if my component is at the root ("/"), as with the "Accounts" component below, then Axios loads the data correctly, no problems here.

But if I went to the "Campaigns" component, which is nested at "/accounts/:account_id" then Axios stops working. In fact, it doesn't return any data at all. However, the API is valid, as Postman correctly returns the data.

So whenever I move a component into a nested URL, Axios stops working. I have no idea why this is happening, and I cannot find any solutions online. I'm sure it must be simple, but I can't see it.

**app.js (Includes routes)**

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
mode: 'history',
routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'accounts',
        component: Accounts
    },
    {
        path: '/accounts/:account_id',
        name: 'campaigns',
        component: Campaigns
    },
],
});
```

**Campaigns Component**

```js
<script>
   import axios from 'axios'

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                accountID:  null,
                campaigns: [],
                campaignsMeta: {},
            };
        },

        mounted() {
          this.accountID = this.$route.params.account_id;
          this.fetchCampaigns();
        },

        methods : {
          fetchCampaigns(page = 1) {
            const AuthStr = 'Bearer '. concat(this.apitoken);
            axios.get("api/account/" + this.accountID + "?page=" + page)
              .then(({data}) => {
                this.campaigns = data.data;
                this.campaignsMeta = data.meta;
            });
          }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is experiencing a similar problem in the future, I made the error of using a relative URL and not an absolute URL for the Axios Get request.

**Original Code**

```js
axios.get("api/account/" + this.accountID + "?page=" + page)
  .then(({data}) => {
    this.campaigns = data.data;
    this.campaignsMeta = data.meta;
});
```

**Correct Code**

```js
axios.get("/api/account/" + this.accountID + "?page=" + page)
  .then(({data}) => {
    this.campaigns = data.data;
    this.campaignsMeta = data.meta;
});
```

Note the "/" at the start of "/api/account" indicating an absolute path, not relative.

The reason this is important is because:

- For relative URLs, the API request would be appended to the end of the current page URL, so the API request on the Accounts component would have been: /accounts/:account_id/api/account (which is wrong!)
- For absolute URLs, the API request is made from the domain name, so the API request on the Accounts component is: domain.com/api/account (correct!)

Thanks!